# My Admob dont show in my app android studio

Tags: java, android

hi my admob dont show in app

Show Touch Set
    Show Touch Unset

```
<string name="admob_banner" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-6229898878120454/4445885975</string>
<string name="admob_full" translatable="false">ca-app-pub-6229898878120454/7124020207</string>
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the test keys from AdMob.
If they work, your ad will work after publishing on google play.